# Building a HTML table using MySQL/PHP results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a dynamic HTML table (regardless of number of columns or rows) from a MySQL query but I think I might be doing something wrong as it doesn't work at all.

I have experience with Oracle but I am new to MySQL. I have tried to check that the MySQL/PHP functions I am using do exist and I think that is the case.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "db");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user")) {
    /* build html table */
    echo "<table class='table '><thread><tr>";

    $ncols = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
        $column_name  = mysqli_field_name($result, $i);
        echo "<th>".$column_name."</th>";
    }

    echo "</tr></thread><tbody>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, OCI_NUM)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ( $ii = 0; $ii < count($row); $ii++ ) {
            echo "<td>" . $row[$ii] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</tbody></table>";

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Appreciating any help!

Steve

**Edit:** I added the error reporting as suggested and get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_field_name() in connection.php on line 20
```

Comment: please explain "Doesn't work at all" : do you get an error message, a blank page, a messed-up HTML result,... ? I might already make a first suggestion even if my PHP skills are a bit rusty : I'm quite sure `mysqli_num_rows` doesn't actually count columns of your table with the query you use... `mysqli_field_count` seems to be what you need...

Comment: Use `print_r` on `$result`, `$ncols` and then on `$row` inside the loop. You will then see what data you have to play with and can work forward from that. Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your document to display errors to the browser. Let us know what you get.

Comment: I'd start with fixing "thread" tag :)

Comment: Another thing: $ncols = mysqli_num_rows($result); - you're assigning number of rows, to variable which, from my understanding, should contain number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is, that you probably converted from `mysql_` functions to `mysqli` which is great! But there is no function `mysqli_field_name()` this function does just exist as a `mysql_` function.

You need the [`mysqli_result::fetch_fields()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) function/method in `mysqli` to get the field names.

Comment: variable assignment in conditional statement is perfectly valid. "if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"))" is the same as "$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); if ($result)"

Comment: @MaciejJaśniaczyk Of course but it doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this condition. If $mysqli->query will return false, conditional statement won't be executed.

Comment: @MaciejJaśniaczyk According to the PHP doc `mysqli::query()` will return `false` or a `mysqli_result` object but never `true` so this if condition will never result in true.

Comment: " For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object". If you pass this object to if statement, it's logical value will be true and code will be executed. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Actually I was trying to convert `oci_` to `mysqli_`! I have this working with Oracle using `oci_`, but now I need to get it working with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a boolean operation not an assignment

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("hostname","username","password","dbname");
$query="select * from table_name";
$sql=mysql_query($query,$link);
if(count($sql)>0)
{
?><tr><th></th>
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    { ?> 
           <tr><td><?php $row['columnname']; ?>
   <?php  } }?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Don't use them anymore!

Comment: for me working good so only i replied. ok thank you for your feedback